# In the anaysis of insertion sort, how did (c1 + c3)(n - 1) become an + b?

Tags: algorithm, math, insertion-sort

I'm reading an analysis of insertion sort. At one point, they say that the runtime is

> (c1 + c3)(n - 1)

and from there rewrite it to

> an + b.

How did they do this?

Comment: its not being converted, it is just showing the complixity in terms of n.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we can multiply through to get that

> (c1 + c3)(n - 1) = (c1 + c3)n - (c1 + c3)

If you now pick a = c1 + c3 and b = -(c1 + c3), then

> (c1 + c3)(n - 1) = (c1 + c3)n - (c1 + c3) = an + b

I think the claim they were making is "there are some choices of a and b we can make such that this sum is an + b," and one choice of those values is given here.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I also have to review my Math to really understand algorithms. Again thank you very very much!